# 415 Unsupported Media Type when ResponseEntity<Map<String, String>> response

Tags: java, resttemplate

I am getting following error while trying to get the following response.

```
private static final ParameterizedTypeReference<Map<String, String>> mapTypeReference = new ParameterizedTypeReference<Map<String, String>>() {
    };


ResponseEntity<Map<String, String>> response = restTemplate.exchange(url, HttpMethod.POST, new HttpEntity<Object>(httpHeaders), mapTypeReference);
```

I am using basic authentication and my headers have the following,

```
httpHeaders.add("someid", "1234");
        httpHeaders.add("someid2", "222");
        httpHeaders.add("Content-Type","text/xml"); // i tried application/json as well 
        httpHeaders.add("Accept","text/xml"); // i tried application/json as well
```

Error:

```
org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException: 415 Unsupported Media Type
        at org.springframework.web.client.DefaultResponseErrorHandler.handleError(DefaultResponseErrorHandler.java:88)
        at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.handleResponseError(RestTemplate.java:537)
        at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:493)
        at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:452)
        at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.exchange(RestTemplate.java:425)
```

Answer (score 0):

For ContentType and Accept headers you can also use this method:

```
HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
headers.setAccept(Arrays.asList(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
```